# How to round the corners of the table in HTML?

Tags: html, css

How to round the corners of the table in HTML? I don't want to use CSS
The source site is PHP
https://mugestan.com/`

I used HTML tags

```
<table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-radius:20px;" bordercolor="#DFDFDF">
```

```
.stspecialslider_container.products_container {border: 5px solid white; border-radius: 5em 5em 5em 5em; padding: 10px 10px 5px 5px; margin: 20px auto;}
```

I don't want to use CSS codes and I can't do this with CSS code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML provides no explicit features for rounding the corners of anything.

Before we got widespread support for `border-radius` in 2011, the hack to produce rounded corners was to add an extra row to the start and end of a table, plus an extra column to the start and end of each row, and then place an image (using `<img>`) of a rounded corner in each of the four corner cells.

Thankfully, it is no longer 2010 as we don't have to resort to such hacks or markup which lies about the semantics of the data being displayed.

I strongly recommend working on removing whatever barrier is preventing you from, and making you not want to use the tool designed to solve this type of problem.

Comment: thanks for your response
We use the verification code inside the cells of the table and I cannot change the verification codes